# Find the equation of the tangents to the circle

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

Find the equation of the tangents to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ which are parallel to $3x+4y-5=0$

My Attempt:
The equation of tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ at point $P(x_1,y_1)$ is given by
$$xx_1+yy_1=4$$
How do I get $x_1$ and $y_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of any straight line parallel to $$3x+4y-5=0$$ is $$3x+4y-c=0$$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Now it will be tangent to the given circle if the radius = the distance of $3x+4y-c=0$ from the center

i.e., $$2=\left|\dfrac{3\cdot0+4\cdot0-c}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}\right|\iff c=?$$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$4=x^2+y^2=\frac{1}{25}(3^2+4^2)(x^2+y^2)\geq\frac{1}{25}(3x+4y)^2.$$
The equality occurs, when $$3x+4y=10$$ and $$3x+4y=-10$$ are touching to the circle.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one forms of the tangents to a circle, the **key is to realize when to use which form of tangent**. Here, you're given the slope of the tangent, hence, the best way to proceed is to use the slope form of the tangent to a circle:

$$y=mx\pm r\cdot\sqrt{1+m^2}$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: @ Gaurang Tandon, Where and how does it come from? Any elaboration

Comment: @blue_eyed_... To derive it, you need to assume tangent as $L$ being $y=mx+c$. Then, put $\text{perpendicular distance from center of circle to } L=\text{radius of circle}$ to get value of $c$ directly. You will find this derivation in any standard introductory book on coordinate geometry of circles. This concept is taught along with the form $xx_1+yy_1=r^2$ for the tangents.

Comment: @blue_eyed_... See the related derivation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2013637/how-to-find-equation-of-a-tangent-to-a-circle-which-is-parallel-to-some-line)

Comment: @blue_eyed_... This is [another derivation](http://doubleroot.in/lessons/circle/tangent-slope-form-1/#.Wj_YOEmWbIU) for same result

Answer (score 0):

Given two lines having equation $r:ax+by+c=0;\;r':a'x+b'y+c'=0$

Then $r\parallel r' \Leftrightarrow ab'-a'b=0$

In this case

$xx_1+yy_1-4=0$ is parallel to $3x+4y-5=0$ if

$\begin{cases}
4x_1-3y_1=0\\
x_1^2+y_1^2=4\\
\end{cases}$

Which gives

$$\left(\frac{6}{5};\;\frac{8}{5}\right);\;\left(-\frac{6}{5};\;-\frac{8}{5}\right)$$

and then

$3 x+4 y-10=0;\;3 x+4 y+10=0$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

From where you have left off,

$$xx_1+yy_1=4\  \ \  \  (1)$$ will be parallel to $$3x+4y-5=0\  \ \  \  (2)$$ iff $\dfrac{x_1}3=\dfrac{y_1}4=F$(say)

$(1)$ becomes $$3Fx+4Fy=4\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Again using algebraic rule,

$$F=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{x_1^2+y^2_1}{3^2+4^2}}=?$$ as $(x_1,y_1)$ lies on $x^2+y^2=4$